# The multi-part identifer "" can not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting the error "The multi-part identifier "Company.Id" could not be bound." on the block of code below on the last Company.Id of the code. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

```
declare @ModuleId int
set @ModuleId = 3

Select Top 1 Vehicle.Id 
From dbo.Vehicle (NoLock) 
Join 
(
        Select InventoryCompany.CompanyId As Id
    From dbo.InventoryCompany (NoLock) 
        Join dbo.Inventory (NoLock) On Inventory.Id = InventoryCompany.InventoryId
        Join dbo.Module(NoLock) On Module.Content = Inventory.Id  
    Where dbo.Module.Id = @ModuleId
)CompanyIds On Company.Id = Vehicle.CompanyId
```

Answer (score 5):

On your last line, change:

`CompanyIds On Company.Id = Vehicle.CompanyId`

To:

`CompanyIds On CompanyIds.Id = Vehicle.CompanyId`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your identifier to `CompanyIds`

```
declare @ModuleId int
set @ModuleId = 3

Select Top 1 Vehicle.Id 
From dbo.Vehicle (NoLock) 
Join 
(
        Select InventoryCompany.CompanyId As Id
    From dbo.InventoryCompany (NoLock) 
        Join dbo.Inventory (NoLock) On Inventory.Id = InventoryCompany.InventoryId
        Join dbo.Module(NoLock) On Module.Content = Inventory.Id  
    Where dbo.Module.Id = @ModuleId
)CompanyIds 
ON CompanyIds.Id = Vehicle.CompanyId
```

Answer (score 1):

You named the subquery `CompanyIds` and that is what you should use

```
declare @ModuleId int
set @ModuleId = 3

Select Top 1 Vehicle.Id 
From dbo.Vehicle (NoLock) 
Join 
(
        Select InventoryCompany.CompanyId As Id
    From dbo.InventoryCompany (NoLock) 
        Join dbo.Inventory (NoLock) On Inventory.Id = InventoryCompany.InventoryId
        Join dbo.Module(NoLock) On Module.Content = Inventory.Id  
    Where dbo.Module.Id = @ModuleId
) CompanyIds On CompanyIds.Id = Vehicle.CompanyId
```